# Shuffle a copy of a list

Tags: python

It seems that the copy of a list is shuffled too?

So if I do for 2 lists:

```
data = examples
np.random.shuffle(examples)
```

then the list data is also shuffled? Why?

Comment: this is because python uses references for lists under the hood. This is more efficient in terms of memory usage.

Comment: This isn't a copy, it's an alias.

Comment: So, when do I know if I make an assignment with "=" python takes noth objects as an aliases?! Is this for all objects in python also for classes? I I want two seperate objects I have to use copy() or deepcopy()?

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't create copies of objects when it thinks they're not needed.

In your case you can use built-in [copy](https://docs.python.org/3/library/copy.html) module:

```py
import copy

data = copy.deepcopy(examples)
np.random.shuffle(examples)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to do examples = [np.copy(data)](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.copy.html) because otherwise the two variables will reference the same position in memory meaning they both change.